# Returning custom error type vs just creating new errors

Tags: go

Let's assume for shake of simplicity I have a simple function that just tries to open a file based on a string passed as parameter (do not rely on the simplicity of the file opening process, given that the actual example will be more convoluted)

```golang
func retrieveConfig(fs billy.Filesystem, app string) (Spec, error) {
    var v Spec
    filename := "releases/" + app + ".yaml"
    file, err := fs.Open(filename)

    if err != nil {
        errOpenFile := ErrOpeningConfigFile{filename}
        return Spec{}, new errOpenFile{filename}
    }
```

Here is the definition of the custom error I am using

```
type ErrOpeningConfigFile struct {
    s string
}

func (errConfigFileNotFound *ErrOpeningConfigFile) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Error opening configuration file %s")
}
```

I thought of following this approach because my idea is that it would give more coverage and make the core more testable.

I can test the error paths more easily now given that I can type assert on the custom error in my unit tests.

However this definitely increases the codebase.

I assume the other way around is to just

```golang
return nil, errors.New("Configuration file not found")
```

that would limit the code, but make testing clumsier (or more narrowed scoped).

What is the appropriate (or Go idiomatic way) of going about this?

Comment: `fmt.Errorf("could not open config file: %w", err)`

Comment: There's not a simple, SO-scopable, answer to this question. I've been working on a blog post on this topic in my head for quite a while. It will probably be 2000+ words. TL;DR; It depends. For a simple answer that gives the necessary flexibility in most cases: Simply wrap your errors as @zerkms suggested.

Comment: Do post link to that blog post whenever is ready. However, you still can't type assert to the error returned by `fmt.Errorf`, right? You can just add more context.

Comment: Using the `: %w` wrapper, you can use `errors.Is` and `errors.As` (provided you're up to date with Go, these were new in 1.13; for older versions, there's golang.orgx/errors).